# What data structure can I use to support constant time random lookup and membership?

Tags: java, data-structures

Essentially, I have a set of objects that I need to be able to (efficiently) select randomly from.  After struggling for a little while, I ended up creating both a Map and a Set (so I could do map.get(randomInt), and set.contains(object)).  But this seems very dirty to me.

Is there any built-in data structure that could support this?  If not, is there a typical abstract data structure?  If not, what is the best way to implement this without having two copies of the data?

Comment: It's likely that you *don't* have two copies of the data - your set and map probably both just contain references to the same data objects.

Comment: Simple list should work? list.get(random index between 0 - n)?

Comment: @SMA How do I see if an item is in the list?

Comment: Why isn't just the `Map` enough? How many entries are in the `Map`? What percentage of overall program time, _as actually measured_, does the lookup operation consume? It might not be worth it to "improve" anything.

Comment: @LewBloch There could be hundreds of thousands to a million maybe?  I agree that doing a sequential search for the random element could be fast enough in practice, but full disclosure - this came from an interview question, and I'm curious about the "best" way to do it.  This very well may be the best way, but I don't know if having an O(n) complexity for getRandom() passes the "smell test" in an interview setting (at least to me).